# Very simple particle filters algorithm (sequential monte carlo method) implementation

Tags: monte-carlo, sequential-analysis, particle-filter

I'm interested in [the simple algorithm for particles filter given here](http://www.aiqus.com/upfiles/PFAlgo.png). It seems very simple but I have no idea on how to do it practically. Any idea on how to implement it (just to better understand how it works) ?

**Edit:**
[This is a great simple example](http://www.aiqus.com/questions/39942/very-simple-particle-filters-algorithm-sequential-monte-carlo-method-implementation?page=1#39950)  that explain how it works. I've tried to implement it in C++: [see my code here](http://pastebin.com/M1q1HcN4), but I'm note sure if I do it the right way. Can you please check if I understood it well, or there are some misunderstanding according to my code ?

Comment: I am not trying to go into your question in any detail but the example you cite seems obvious to me. p(xt|x(i)t−1) is a conditional probability distribution and the statement is simple to draw  x(i)t from that conditional probability distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick well, I've edited my post to add a simple C++ implementation of a simple example. Can you please check if I understood it well, or there are some misunderstanding ?

Answer (score 4):

What that sentence means is you should generate $x_t^{(i)}$ from the distribution of $p(x_t|x^{(i)}_{t−1})$.

For an alternative introduction to [particle filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) I recommend [An Overview of Existing Methods and Recent Advances in Sequential Monte Carlo](http://www.irisa.fr/aspi/legland/ref/cappe07a.pdf)

MATLAB has [numerous toolboxes on particle filters](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=%22particle+filter%22). If you are working in C++, [here is an implementation](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v30/i06/) you can use to compare your code with.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this resources. Well, I want to implement particle filters alone from scrach just to understand it. I've edited my post to add a simple C++ implementation of a simple example. Can you please check if I understood it well, or there are some misunderstanding ?

Comment: I can't error-check it mentally and I don't have the time to compile it. I suggest you test it with synthetic data and check the reference code I just provided.

Comment: The other implementations seems complicated, I just wanted to implement this "very" simple one: http://www.aiqus.com/upfiles/PFAlgo.png on an example with two states. If I provide the algorithm of how I understood it (instead of code) can you check it ?

Comment: What does it mean when one say: "Sample N times with replacement from the set of particles $x_t^{(i)}$ according to importance weights $w_t^{(i)}$

Comment: It means you should [sample with replacement](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm%5D) with a probability of selecting a particle proportional to its weight. See [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwg_KI3UewY&feature=relmfu) by Sebastian Thrun.

Answer (score 2):

The [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) package [RcppSMC](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppSMC) implements three simple models from the literature.

Answer (score 1):

@user995434 I do not program in C++ and don't think I would understand your code well enough to indicate how well you understood my point. Maybe you can explain what you are doing and that way I can comment.  All that I was saying is that you know the value of the process at time t-1 and then conditioned on that value you generate the value for the process at time t by drawing a random value from the conditional distribution. You must specify an initial value X0 but after that each X is sampled from its distribution conditional on the value of the previous X.